# Recording iPad Video Output on Mac

Tags: ipad, video

I'd like to record video output from my iPad on my Mac.  I know there is a VGA output adapter for the iPad.  What hardware and software do I need on the Mac side?

Details:

- I have a two-year-old iMac and year-old MacBook.  I can use either one for the recording.
- I will be recording an iPad app that has support for video output (it's an app I'm developing myself)
- I don't care much about what the final video format is.  Ideally, QuickTime, but really anything displayable on a Mac is fine.

Alternatively, if there is a much easier/cheaper way to record on a Windows box rather than Mac, I could do that too.

Answer (score 2):

There's a guide [here](http://www.screencapturenews.com/2010/05/25/capture-and-record-video-from-apple-ipad/) you might find helpful. The guide suggests using the [iPad VGA connector](http://store.apple.com/uk/product/MC552ZM/A?fnode=MTc0MjU4NjE&mco=MTczMTA1MTE) and a VGA to USB converter. The suggested converter is a bit steep at $299, but you might be able to find a cheaper alternative.